# Test suite fails to run

Tags: py-datatable

I followed the instructions in https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start/install.html to build datatable from the git repo. My tests are failing when I run step 5 in the section **Install datatable in editable mode**. I have attached a part of my error log.

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIU4v.png)

Comment: you could create an issue on the [github](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable) page and someone should respond. Also, I assume you created a virtual env, cloned the repo, and are working within the virtual environment?

Comment: Thanks, I created an issue on the github. Yeah, I did everything within the virtual environment, that is, building, linking and running all the tests, where it failed. Even though the test suite failed, I am still able to "import datatable" inside my python interpreter successfully.